# If the conditional expectation of the random variable does follow a linear function, can we show the probability a particular data set happens?

Tags: statistical-inference, regression, hypothesis-testing

Suppose that $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x]=\beta_0+\beta_1x$ where $X, Y$ are random varibles. Given a set of observations consisting pairs of $X,Y$, is it possible to attach it as probabiltiy density function?

The motivation of this question is a more fundamental thing that I am seeking help with. I want to know if it is possible to perform a hypothesis test testing whether the true specification of the equation is in fact linear without any transformation of the random vaibles, that is, $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x]=\beta_0+\beta_1x$, given a set of pairs $X,Y$. To do this, I have to assume the specification is true and compute the p-value for theset of pairs $X,Y$. However, to do this, I have to first compute the null distribution. And I am pretty much lost at this point. My professor told me that such test does not exist, would any one help me continue my thought process please? Thanks.

**some futher thoughts**
The problem is it is hard to come up with a null distribution. In a one-sample mean test, we suppose the true population mean and deduce the distribution of the sample mean. Similarly, in this problem, we should suppose a true specification, or the realtionship between $X$ and $Y$ for populationand, then deduce the distribution of possible investigated relationship between them for a random sample. But how can we actually do that?

My idea is what characterize the need for a regression is the random variable $\epsilon$. If we can characterize the variance this $\epsilon$, assuming it is normal, we can in some sense show how legit does a particular pair $(x_k,y_k)$ fits the equation $y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i+\epsilon_i$. In other words, if we have a pair of realized $X$ and $Y$ and suppose we know $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, we can treat the $\epsilon_i$ as a realized value of the random varible $\epsilon$. And it is relatively easy to come up with a distribution of $\epsilon$ and test the p-value of $\epsilon_i$. However, the problem is we don't really know what $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ in the null distribution, since we testing for the specifcition for all possible $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, not just a single pair of $\beta$ (Let us assume for the time being $\epsilon$ is known for simplification.)  Then is it possible to come up witha way to synthesis all possible pair of $\beta$ and test for the null?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what  you are asking for. For model misspecification problems, you can start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_RESET_test). For testing an estimated vector of $\beta$ vs. some alternative set of values, you can simply use the [F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test), assuming that $\epsilon$ is normal distributed.

Comment: THe Ramsey RESET test is what I am looking for. Thanks.